# SQLite: insert as Integer and as Text

Tags: sqlite

Given we have a simple table like

```
CREATE TABLE A(
  amount INTEGER
);
```

What is the difference between queries

```
INSERT INTO A VALUES(4);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO A VALUES('12');
```

As seen in schema, amount is an INTEGER column. The first query operates with just that - an integer, but the second one operates with a string '12'. Yet both queries work just fine, the table gets values 4 and 12, and can select or, say, sum them up correctly as two valid Integers:

```
SELECT sum(amount) AS "Total" FROM A;
```

correctly yields 16.

So is there a difference between inserting an integer as (4) and inserting it as ('12') into the INTEGER-type column?

Comment: Read all about "Type Affinity" in the [manual](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: @SBF "The type affinity of a column is the recommended type for data stored in that column. The important idea here is that the type is recommended, not required. Any column can still store any type of data." - wow. So it is actually stored as an int and a text within the same column

Comment: Or rather, text data is being "converted" into an integer "When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column, the storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL (in order of preference)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite tries to convert your String into an Integer before inserting the value into your table as [described in the manual](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

> The type affinity of a column is the recommended type for data stored in that column. The important idea here is that the type is recommended, not required. Any column can still store any type of data. It is just that some columns, given the choice, will prefer to use one storage class over another.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the case indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Important here is that the conversion has to be lossless and reversible.  _When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column, the storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL (in order of preference) if such conversion is lossless and reversible. For conversions between TEXT and REAL storage classes, SQLite considers the conversion to be lossless and reversible if the first 15 significant decimal digits of the number are preserved. If the lossless conversion of TEXT to INTEGER or REAL is not possible then the value is stored using the TEXT storage class._